# Is there any way to combine range queries for different fields in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I know that the firestore does not support range queries on different fields ([as per the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)).

But I ran into a situation where I needed to check the quantity > 0 and order by discount percentage.

Like this

```
db.collection("Inventory").where("availableQuantity", ">", 0).orderBy("discountPercentage", "desc").get();
```

Can anyone help me with achieving this functionality?
Or suggest me a different data model to store the data.

here's the current data model
[image]

Comment: What is the exact query you intend to perform?

Comment: @AlexMamo       db.collection("Inventory").where("availableQuantity", ">", 0).orderBy("discountPercentage", "desc").get();

Comment: Have you tried to add 'availableQuantity' as your first orderBy() field?

Comment: Another suggestion, add a `bool` field called `availableQuantityGreaterThan0`. Keep it updated using cloud functions. Then run your query like this: `db.collection("Inventory").where("availableQuantityGreaterThan0", "==", true).orderBy("discountPercentage", "desc").get();`

Comment: @PeterO. that's awesome. A simple and elegant solution, I never thought of that. I'll try.

Comment: @PeterO. Feel like writing that up in an answer? 

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried your solution, but it is ignoring the other "orerBy" fields. 
For Ex: 
db.collection("Inventory")
.where("availableQuantity", ">", 0)
.orderBy("availableQuantity", "desc")
.orderBy("discountPercentage", "desc")
.limit(10)
.get();

//only .orderBy("availableQuantity", "desc") is considered & the orderBy("discountPercentage", "desc") is ignored but the query.

Comment: The second orderBy will work only if two elements that are coming from the first order have the availableQuantity equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest a different data model to enable you run your query.

add a `bool` field called `availableQuantityGreaterThan0`.

Keep it updated using cloud functions. Then run your query like this:

```
db.collection("Inventory")
  .where("availableQuantityGreaterThan0", "==", true)
  .orderBy("discountPercentage", "desc").get();
```

Example cloud function to keep the field updated:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.onUpdate = functions.firestore
  .document("/Inventory/{inventory_id}")
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const params = context.params;
    const inventoryId = params.inventory_id;
    const inventory = change.after.data();
    const availableQuantityGreaterThan0 = inventory.availableQuantity > 0;

    return db.doc("/Inventory/" + inventoryId)
      .set({ availableQuantityGreaterThan0 }, { merge: true });
  });
```

Do this for `onCreate` also.